# ¿Cómo solucionar el error org.codehaus.mojo: exec-maven-plugin: 1.2.1: exec al compilar en Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

Tengo un proyecto de Nomina para compilar en Maven un error

> Error al ejecutar el objetivo org.codehaus.mojo: exec-maven-plugin: 1.2.1: exec (default-cli) en el proyecto
>   mavenproject1: Falló la ejecución del comando. Proceso salido con un
>   error: 1 (valor de salida: 1) -> [Ayuda 1]
>
> Para ver el rastro completo de la pila de los errores, vuelva a ejecutar Maven con el modificador -e.
>      Vuelva a ejecutar Maven utilizando el modificador -X para habilitar el registro de depuración completo.
>
> Para obtener más información sobre los errores y posibles soluciones, lea los siguientes artículos:
>      [Ayuda 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Me podrian ayudar a solucionar este error ... Muchas gracias

Comment: Haz un `Rebuild y Clean` del proyecto, muchas con eso es suficiente para resolver ese error.

Comment: y si no funciona ? ... excepto falla en el codigo ... que otro error podria existir ?

Comment: Corre con el modificador -e y de paso con -X para ver que error pudiera ser